# how to change the index value of numpy array with column values of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I have a dataframe:
    data:

```
  user_id   item_id rating
0    772       36    3
1    471      228    5
2    641      401    4
3    312       98    4
4     58      504    5
```

I have created a array of random number, whose size equal to unique values in item_id

```
a = np.random.random(1662)
```

Now I want to convert index value of array as column value of item_id. How to change index of array.
Item_id has total 1662 value but it is not continues like 1 to 1662. there are some values missing. the maximum value being 1681. So what I need is to create a random array of size 1662(i.e equal to unique values of item_id). But if i want to see random value associated with a index (1677) how can i see that?

Since size of array is 1662 so the maximum index value is 1661 for index.
so i want to associate 1662 number with the values of item_id

Comment: The question is unclear. May be an example would help in understanding what exactly you want to achieve.

Also, in pandas, you can set a column as index_column with `data.set_index('item_id')`

Comment: @dumbPy i want to set the index of numpy array a with the column item_id.

Comment: You can't set index for a numpy array. You can set index for a pandas dataframe or use dict in that case.
If you want to set a random number for each unique item in the item_id column, you can use a dictionary as   
```item_id2num = {
  _id:random.randint(0, <some_upper_limit>)
  for _id in data.item_id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems vague.

You have a random array with 1662 unique values in item_id - meaning that its possible a value exists in item_id and its also possible that it doesn't. If it does, you want to re-index the numpy array a according to the value - so if the number 36 is in 'a' and in 'item_id' you want a[36] = 36?

Please clarify.

If that's what you want, then simply create an ordered list of every item_id like so:

```
a = np.arrange(max(data.item_id))
b = np.isin(a, data.item_id)
a[b] = np.full(a[b], data.item_id)
```

> UPDATE: For a[36] = random-number

```
a[b] = np.full(a[b], np.random.normal())
```

**Suggestion**:
You can also add random numbers inside your dataframe as:

```
data['random'] = np.random.random(data.count())
# create a dict for indexing
random_dict = dict(zip(data['item_id'].tolist(), data['random'].tolist()))
# or set item_id as index:
data.index = data['item_id'].values
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: i dont want a[36] = 36. i want if a 36 present in item id then there should be random number present in array a with that index i.e a[36] = random number

Comment: this is giving me error as ValueError: sequence too large; cannot be greater than 32